# How can I implement double dispatch when I don't know all the classes in advance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, typeid, double-dispatch, extensible

I've got a base class with (potentially) a lot of subclasses, and I would like to be able to compare any two objects of the base class for equality. I am trying to do this without invoking the blasphemous typeid keyword.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {

    virtual bool operator==(const Base& rhs) const
        {return rhs.equalityBounce(this);}

    virtual bool equalityBounce(const Base* lhs) const = 0;
    virtual bool equalityCheck(const Base* lhs) const = 0;
};

struct A : public Base {

    A(int eh) : a(eh) {}
    int a;

    virtual bool equalityBounce(const Base* lhs) const{
        return lhs->equalityCheck(this);
    }

    virtual bool equalityCheck(const Base* rhs) const {return false;}
    virtual bool equalityCheck(const A* rhs) const {return a == rhs->a;}
};


int main() {

    Base *w = new A(1), *x = new A(2);

    std::cout << (*w == *w) << "\n";
    std::cout << (*w == *x) << "\n";
}
```

I understand that the code as written is failing because lhs in equalityBounce() is a Base*, so it doesn't even know about the version of equalityCheck() that takes an A*. But I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: To be honest I think for this you need an external equality checker - a set of overloaded free functions (or bound in a class if you like) that know how to compare the various types. When you add a new type, you need to add some new functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Double Dispatch for Equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393458/c-double-dispatch-for-equals)

Comment: @Pradhan ATTENTION:  It's not a full duplicate of the other SO question.  Both relate to equal with double dispatch. This one introduces the constraint of extensibility that is not mentionned nor addressed in the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work**

The problem with your double dispatch implementation is that you expect that the most specific `equalityCheck()` is called.

But your implementation is totaly based on a polymorphic base class, and `equalityCheck(const A*)` overloads but **does not override** `equalityCheck(const Base*)` !

Otherwhise said, at compile time the compiler knows that `A::equalityBounce()` could call `equalityCheck(A*)` (because `this` is an `A*`), but unfortunately it calls `Base::equalityCheck()` which has no specialised version for an `A*` parameter.

**How to implement it ?**

For the double dispatch to work, you need to have type specific implementations of the double dispatched equalityCheck() in your base class.

For this to work,  the Base needs to be aware of its descendents:

```
struct A; 

struct Base {

    virtual bool operator==(const Base& rhs) const
    {
        return rhs.equalityBounce(this);
    }

    virtual bool equalityBounce(const Base* lhs) const = 0;
    virtual bool equalityCheck(const Base* lhs) const = 0;
    virtual bool equalityCheck(const A* lhs) const = 0;
};

struct A : public Base {
    ...
    bool equalityBounce(const Base* lhs) const override{  
        return lhs->equalityCheck(this);
    }
    bool equalityCheck(const Base* rhs) const override {
        return false; 
    }
    bool equalityCheck(const A* rhs) const override{
        return a == rhs->a;
    }
};
```

*Note the use of `override` to make sure that the function really overrides a virtual function of the base.*

With this implementation it will work, because:

- `A::equalityBounce()` will call `Base::equalityCheck()`
- among all the overloaded versions of this function, it will choose the `Base::equalityCheck(A*)` because `this` is an `A*`
- the invoked `Base *lhs` object will call its `equalityCheck(A*)`.  If `lhs` is an `A*`  it will hence go for `A::equalityCheck(A*)` which will produce the expected (correct) result. **Congratulations !**
- suppose `lhs` would be a pointer to another class `X` also derived from `Base`.  In this case, `lhs->equalityCheck(A*)` would call `X::equalityCheck(A*)` and could also return the correct response, taking into consideration that you'd compare an `X` with an `A`.

**How to make it extensible ? The double-dispatch map !**

The problem with the double dispatch using a strongly typed language, is that the "bounced" object needs to know about how to compare to specific (known in advance) classes.  As your source object and your bounced object are of the same polymorphic base type, the base needs hence to know all involved types.  This design limits seriously the extensivbility.

If you want to be able to add any derived type without knowing it in advance in the base class, then you have to go through dynamic types (be it dynamic_cast or typeid):

I propose you here a proposal for dynamic EXTENSIBILITY.  It uses single dispatch for comparing two objects of the same type, and a **double-dispatch map** to compare different types between them (returning by default false if nothing was declared):

```
struct Base {
    typedef bool(*fcmp)(const Base*, const Base*);  // comparison function
    static unordered_map < type_index, unordered_map < type_index, fcmp>> tcmp;  // double dispatch map

    virtual bool operator==(const Base& rhs) const
    {
        if (typeid(*this) == typeid(rhs)) {  // if same type, 
            return equalityStrict(&rhs);     // use a signle dispatch
        }
        else {                              // else use dispatch map.  
            auto i = tcmp.find(typeid(*this));
            if (i == tcmp.end() ) 
                return false;              // if nothing specific was foreseen...
            else {
                auto j = i->second.find(typeid(rhs));
                return j == i->second.end() ? false : (j->second)(this, &rhs);
            }
        }
    }
    virtual bool equalityStrict(const Base* rhs) const = 0;  // for comparing two objects of the same type
};
```

The A class would then be rewrtitten as:

```
struct A : public Base {
    A(int eh) : a(eh) {}
    int a;
    bool equalityStrict(const Base* rhs) const override {  // how to compare for the same type
        return (a == dynamic_cast<const A*>(rhs)->a); 
        }
};
```

With this code, you can compare any objects with an object of the same type.  Now to show extensibility, I've created a `struct X`, with the same members than `A`. If I want to allow to copare A with X, I just have to define a comparison function:

```
bool iseq_X_A(const Base*x, const Base*a) {
    return (dynamic_cast<const X*>(x)->a == dynamic_cast<const A*>(a)->a);
}  // not a member function, but a friend.
```

Then to make dynamic double dipatch work, I have to add this function to the double-dispatch map:

```
Base::tcmp[typeid(X)][typeid(A)] = iseq_X_A;
```

Then the resutls are easy to verify:

```
Base *w = new A(1), *x = new A(2), *y = new X(2);
std::cout << (*w == *w) << "\n";  // true returned by A::equalityStrict
std::cout << (*w == *x) << "\n";  // false returned by A::equalityStrict 
std::cout << (*y == *x) << "\n";  // true returned by isseq_X_A
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a virtual equals operator and you want to avoid a dynamic_cast you could add an enum type to your base class that indicates type and make a virtual getter and then do static cast if it matches.

```
enum ClassType { AType, BType };
Class A 
{
public:

virtual ClassType getType ();
virtual bool operator ==(const A& a ) const;
};

// in B implementation

virtual bool B::operator ==(const A& a)
{
if (!A::operator==(a)) return false;
if(a.getType () != ClassType::BType) return false;
const B& b = static_cast <const& B>(a);
// do B == checks
return true;
}
```

Comment: You're right: this is an alternative.  However with your enum and `getType()` you'd have a solution very close to the `dynamic_cast` alternative.  It's certainly a valid solution when only objects of the same derived class need to be compared.  But if you'd have many different comparison/conversion rules between "sister classes", you'd have a lot of very complex `operator==`, having to provide for all posible subtype combinations.

Comment: True, the idea is to avoid performance overhead of a series of dynamic casts.  The asker was looking specifically for solution for a type hierarchy.  If other types of comparisons are valid then you are correct that it would be better to provide additional free functions that implement this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Altough slow due to the `dynamic_cast`, I think the most comfortable solution is the next one:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual bool operator==(const Base& rhs) const
    { return equalityBounce(&rhs); }

    virtual bool equalityBounce(const Base* lhs) const = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
struct BaseHelper : public Base
{
    bool equalityBounce(const Base* rhs) const
    {
        const Derived* p_rhs = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(rhs);

        if (p_rhs == nullptr)
            return false;
        else
            return p_rhs->equalityCheck
             (reinterpeter_cast<const Derived*>(this));
    }

    virtual bool equalityCheck(const Derived*) const = 0;
};

struct A : public BaseHelper<A> {

    A(int eh) : a(eh) {}
    int a;

    virtual bool equalityCheck(const A* rhs) const
    { return a == rhs->a; }
};


int main() {

   Base *w = new A(1), *x = new A(2);

   std::cout << (*w == *w) << "\n"; // Prints 1.
   std::cout << (*w == *x) << "\n"; // Prints 0.
}
```

In this way, you have to only to be care about comparing objects of same derived typed as "me". You don't need to write more overloads because BaseHelper makes all the auxiliary work for you.